# SQL request in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to do a SQL-request within my php-page.
Currently, the code looks like:

```
$activiteitname = mysql_query("SELECT titel FROM tblLeidingAgenda WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");
$message = 'Herinnering!';
mail('me@test.be', 'Reminder: '.$activiteitname.'', $message);
```

But on execution, I get an `Resource id #15` error...

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a handler, you should use a function to fetch the results.

Comment: You should learn how to use MySQL in PHP and addtitonally read some docs about preventing SQL-injection.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_query returns a handler but you can retirve that result with [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

```
<?php $activiteitname = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT titel
                                            FROM tblLeidingAgenda 
                                            WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])."'"),0,'titel');
?>
```

Comment: Why for is the `,0,'titel');` at the end? This one solved my problem by the way!

Comment: it means, 0 row or first row... and the column `titel`

Answer (score 3):

When MySQL returns data to PHP, the information is put into a variable called a `resource special data type`. When you attempt to treat this as if it were a `string data type`, all that it 'reveals' is the `ResouceID`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$activiteitname = mysql_query("SELECT titel FROM tblLeidingAgenda WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}'");

var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($activiteitname));
```

Comment: and escape data - mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.